# Why is rst2html5 messing up encodings?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, character-encoding

I have a Python program which is written in UTF-8 as confirmed by PyCharm and Sublime Text. It prints out the pound character, `£` (`0xC2 0xA3`), to a reStructured Text:

[image]

Opening the reStructured Text file with PyCharm and Sublime Text it looks fine and both claim it's UTF-8.

The problem comes when I generate HTML out of this file by using [rst2html5](https://pypi.org/project/rst2html5/), with this command:

```
 rst2html5 --input-encoding=utf-8 --output-encoding=utf-8 foo.rst > foo.html
```

The HTML claims to be UTF-8, by means of `<meta charset="utf-8" />`, but the pound characters, `£`, are now shown as `┬ú`. Opening it in Sublime Tex as UTF-8 also shows `┬ú` instead of `£`. This is the actual data:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on or how to stop it? Does that look like UTF-8 at all?

The generated file starts like this:

[image]

`0xFF 0xFE` reminds me of the [UTF-16 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) but setting the header to `<meta charset="utf-16" />` does not solve the problem and telling a text editor to open the file as UTF-16 still shows the non ASCII character broken.

In case it is relevant, my active Windows code page is 437.

Comment: "Claims to" but isn't? Or is it actually? What are the hex bytes used for encoding the £ character? In UTF-8, it should be 0xC2 0xA3.

Comment: Are you viewing the HTML file locally? Does it have a `http-equiv` header identifying its encoding? If you are viewing it from a web server, what headers are the server attaching?

Comment: @tripleee: I added some information about what I mean by claims to. Let me get a hex editor and I'll get the actual bytes, but having dealt with many encoding issues bellow, I'm reasonable certain it's not a decoding problem, but an encoding one.

Comment: @tripleee: I'm viewing the file locally, Chrome on Windows.

Comment: What you see is completely irrelevant without information about what fonts etc you have.  See also [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: @tripleee: I understand fonts would have an effect on uncommon characters, but pretty much every font and certainly every default font has the pound character in it.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the page I linked to. Here is the link again: [link](/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: @tripleee: I read the page. You asked for the hex representation and I got it. I still don't see your point about fonts. rst2html5 is not outputing `0xC2 0xA3` when it encounters `0xC2 0xA3` when I specified utf-8 as both inputs and outputs and fonts have no effect there.

Comment: Looks like the output is some flavour of UTF-16 too…!?

Comment: @deceze: that's what I thought, but I'm thankfully not too familiar with looking at UTF-16 at this level (or with UTF-16 encoding problems). Most of what I had to deal with utf-8 vs latin-1, latin-15, etc.

Comment: @deceze: the file starts with `0xFF 0xFE`, which is the UTF-16 BOM, so, I think you are right and it's UTF-16

Comment: (Almost) every other character in the hex editor being 00 means it's UTF-16. You could try `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 foo.html` on the document (if you have iconv installed).

Comment: @AKX `2C25FA00` is still nowhere near the correct encoding for £ in UTF-16 though, so even that wouldn't help.

Comment: @AKX: I installed iconv and gave that a try. Yup, not UTF-16.

Comment: You should probably simply ask the author. I presume this is the tool you are talking about: https://github.com/marianoguerra/rst2html5

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question. As the discussion here should amply illustrate, when you see the glyph £ we still have no idea which actual font and encoding you are using. The hex bytes are the only way to unambiguously and succinctly identify what's in the file.

Comment: Locales could be messing things up. What is your Windows code page and are you able to produce valid UTF-8 out of other Python scripts?

Comment: @tripleee: I don't know what my Windows code page is. How do I find out? Yes, I had a Python script that I wrote produce the rst file, which is correct UTF-8.

Comment: I believe [`chcp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) should print your code page, though my usual recommendation is to get rid of Windows entirely if you are having problems.

Comment: @tripleee: I cannot get rid of Windows. Active code page: 437.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being cause by PowerShell redirection and not by rst2html5 itself. Running it like this:

```
 rst2html5 --input-encoding=utf-8 --output-encoding=utf-8 foo.rst foo.html
```

which has the same effect as the redirection (`>`) one worked well, and using the redirection on on CMD also worked well.

*If someone has more information about why PowerShell is messing up the encoding, that'd be good to add here.*